# how to calculate $P(C|A∩B)$ from $P(C)$ $P(C|A)$ and $P(C|B)$ where the universal set is $A\times B$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I don't know if I'm using the right terminology so I'll try to clarify what I mean:

$U=\{(a',b')\mid a'\in A'\ and\ b'\in B'\}$

$a\in A$

$b\in B$

$A=\{(a, b')\mid b'\in B'\}$

$B=\{(a', b)\mid a'\in A'\}$

$C \subset U$

given $P(C|A)$ $P(C|B)$ and $P(C)$ can you solve for $P(C|A∩B)$, if so how, and if not why, and what extra information is needed.

Related questions:

[How to Calculate the conditional probability $P(Z|AB)$ if we know $P(Z)$, $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(Z|A)$, $P(Z|B)$, $P(AB)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470790/how-to-calculate-the-conditional-probability-pzab-if-we-know-pz-pa)

[Estimating conditional probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902005/estimating-conditional-probability?rq=1)

Comment: $P(A∩B)$ cannot equal zero because $A∩B=\{(a,b)\}$

Comment: I think I phrased the question wrong. $P(S)$ should be the cardinality of S divided by the cardinality of U I think.@P.Quinton

Answer (score 1):

Two scenarios can happen since $A\cap B = \{(a,b)\}$. Either $(a,b)\in C$ or not. In the second case your probability is $0$ by definition. In the first you get
\begin{align*}
P(C|A\cap B) &= P(A\cap B\cap C)/P(A\cap B)\\
&= P(\{(a,b)\})/ P(\{(a,b)\})\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

This is all true if and only if $P(A\cap B)>0$, in the case $P(A\cap B)=0$, then $P(C|A\cap B)=0$.

Comment: this may warrant another question altogether, but what is the probability a random subset of U contains {a, b} (assuming all subsets are equally probable) in terms of $P(C|A)$ $P(C|B)$ and $P(C)$?

Comment: it cannot be that all the subsets have same probability since $P(\emptyset)=0\neq 1=P(U)$. If you are talking about having all elements of $U$ have same probability then a random subset contains $\{a,b\}$ with probability $1/2$, indeed the probability that it is not contained in the set is the same and they sum to $1$.